# Simple update syntax needed

Tags: apex

Assume that the splitContactIds field has 3 contact ids separated with commas.

What do I need to add to this code in order to create 3 new records in the Training__c object where the records has a contact lookup field that is required and a Name field that is required? The cane can be any short text for our purposes.

Thanks

Here is what I have

```
 Training__c trn = New Training__c();
        // CSV to list
        if (currentContacts_CSV != null && currentContacts_CSV != ''){
            splitContactIds = currentContacts_CSV.split(',');
            for (String cId:splitContactIds){
                currentContactIds_Set.add(cId);

            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something of this nature should work:

```
Training__c[] ts = new Training__c[] {};
for (String cId : splitContactIds){
    ts.add(new Training__c(Name = 'Training for ' + cId, Contact__c = cId));
}
insert ts;
```